# 20.04 dev packages (libfreetype6-dev) not ready. Skeleton packages

Tags: package-management, 20.04, libraries, development

I have noticed that some dev packages don't contain the full package contents (compared to 18.04) and are just skeleton packages. libfreetype6-dev for instance.

Should I be worried or is this expected until the 20.04.1 release in late July?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the changelogs (at http://changelogs.ubuntu.com ) before assuming the worst. Here's an exerpt from the [changelog for libfreetype6-dev](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/binary/libf/libfreetype6-dev/2.10.1-2/changelog) that explains the difference between 18.04 and 20.04:

```
 * libfreetype6-dev has been renamed to libfreetype-dev.
   - libfreetype6-dev is now a transitional package.
   - Please update your build dependencies accordingly.
```

All packages in 20.04 are complete, 20.04 is finished and released, and developers have moved on to 20.10. If you find a skeletal package *without* an explanation in the changelog or release notes, please file a bug report.